# Как перемешать vector в c++?

Tags: c++

У меня есть vector. Мне надо его перемешать. Что-то вроде random.shuffle в python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Пользуйтесь [`shuffle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle), примерно так:

```
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
 
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
 
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 g(rd());
 
    std::shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), g);
 
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```